# attribute value is not saving in database

Tags: php, javascript, phtml, multi-vendor, database-update

we are using magento marketplace multivendor site.

we gave an option for vendor to update the product details in frontend.

we are using this code for updating the price. its working fine.

**Phtml**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>


<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**JS**

```
function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setPrice($upd_price);
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

In the same way we need to update the custom attribute "local" .

we are using following code to update local. **but its not saving in database**.

attribute code ="local"
attribute value = "Local"

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('local');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>

<?php endif; ?>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" />


<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="local_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>


<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>

</span>
```

**JS**

```
function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controller.php**

```
 public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setLocal($upd_local);

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Comment: if other attribute are saving except the attribute "local" then may be the attribute "local" is not assigned to product's attribute set

Comment: @Piyush its assigned to attribute set. Price is working. first time i am trying with custom attribute

Comment: Remove "Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);" your controller file and try again

Comment: @Abdul i tried, no luck....

Comment: if you are trying save admin side any product with Local attribute value "Test" then working or not

Comment: from admin, its saving succesfully.

Comment: can you share you attribute code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33319/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-abdul).

Comment: @Abdul please check here : http://pastebin.com/BNmx2Tse & http://pastebin.com/3hnN00fQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function updateFieldLocalAction()
    {
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();

        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
            $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
            if($product->getId()) {
                $product->setLocal($upd_local);  
                $product->save();
                echo $local = $product->getLocal();
                echo $name = $product->getName();
            }       

            $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: no, still same result

Comment: if your are debug : $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); print_r(($product ); die; then get you current product or not

Comment: mostly it will come. when i add this code : <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); print_r(($product ); die; ?> i got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'"

Comment: in the same code file ,i am getting price and quantity values

Comment: Pls tried bellow code : 

public function updateFieldLocalAction()
 {
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123);
  try{
   $product->setLocal('test');  
   $product->save();
  }catch(Exception $e){
   $e->getMessage();
  }
 }

Comment: and put any fixed product id for eg -> 123 and check this product admin side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33321/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-abdul).